# Should I still raise exceptions if type hints inform the acceptable types for functions?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, type-hinting

I'm trying to wrap my head around best practices when it comes to hints and exceptions and making them play nice in a consistent manner. In Fluent Python (~p. 283), the author presents an implementation for `__getitem__` for his toy `Vector` class:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, components): 
        self._components = components

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        class = type(self)
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return cls(self._components[index])

        elif isinstance(index, numbers.Integral):
            return self._components[index]

        else:
            msg = '{cls.__name__} indices must be integers'
            raise TypeError(msg.format(cls=cls))
```

The book was written around the advent of 3.4, so I understand the reduced presence of annotations. If I were to implement the above with annotations, I'd imagine something like this:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, components): 
        self._components = components

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> int:
        ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, index: slice) -> Vector:
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        class = type(self)
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return cls(self._components[index])

        elif isinstance(index, numbers.Integral):
            return self._components[index]

        else:
            msg = '{cls.__name__} indices must be integers'
            raise TypeError(msg.format(cls=cls))
```

Firstly, I suspect one would still have to do `___getinstance__` checks, but do let me know if there's a cleaner way.

**My question:** The annotated version makes it clear that the function should either accept an `int` or a `slice`. Is it still best practice to do the `else` leg of the non-annotated version (ie. explicitly raise the exception warning a consumer that the type of `index` is incorrect)? Or is it ok to just drop it and let the `TypeError` exception happen "naturally"?

Comment: The type error *won't* happen naturally. Annotations aren't enforced at runtime.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, and that's because there's a typo in what I pasted above; I'm sorry! `self._components` should be initialized as an `array`, not just whatever the `Iterable` passed in is. In that case, it'll raise a TypeError from `array`, and I realize now that the point of manually catching and raising the exception was to hide the array underneath and clean up the error reporting.